# .click() not working (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have map in my View.

On  marker click I need to open pop-up and this is working fine.

Here is the code for it:

```
 export function  all_hotels_map_results(): void {
Helpers.set_currency_settings();
const json = gon.hotel_info;
const token = "***********";
const centerLatlng = new mapboxgl.LngLat(gon.destination_city.lng, gon.destination_city.lat);
mapboxgl.accessToken = token;
let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: "map-canvas",
      style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9",
      center: centerLatlng,
      zoom: 9
});

map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
map.on('load', function() {
$.each(json, function(i, item) {
  let myLatlng = new mapboxgl.LngLat(item.lng, item.lat);
  let stars = "";
  for(let s = 0; s < item.rating; s++) {
    stars += '<img class="star-image" style="height:20px;width:20px;">';
    }
  const Popup_Content = '<div class="map-card__wrapper">'
  +'<div class="map-card__image-container">'
  +'<div class="map-card__image" style="background: url('+item.pictures[0].url+');">' +'</div>'
  +'</div>'
  +'<div class ="map-card__content-container ">'
  + '<div class ="map-card__title">'+item.name +'</div>'
  +'<p class="map-card__address">'+item.address1+'</p>'
  + '<div class ="map-card__review">'+stars +'</div>'
  + '<div class ="map-card__price-container">'+__("Flygbolag")+ ": "+ accounting.formatMoney(item.sales_prices[0])
  +'</div>'
  + '</div>';

  let marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
    .setLngLat(myLatlng)
    .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 5 })
    .setHTML(Popup_Content))
    .addTo(map);
  });
});
```

};

But I need to get value of  `<div class ="map-card__title">` and I am trying to do it like this:

```
$('.map-card__title').click(function(){
alert();


 })
```

But it does not work. I have no alert messages in console, anything.

Where can be my fault?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The elements to which you are attaching the event listeners are being generated dynamically.

It might happen that these elements were not even created or attached to the **DOM** when your `$('selector').click(fn)` was called.

You should try delegating the event to common parent of these elements like your **Map** itself or even the **body.** That way, your **body** or **Map** listens for the click on each of your children elements, and not these elements themselves.

What I suggest looks pretty much like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.children', function() {});
```

You can read more about these here:

[https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/](http://jQuery%20Event%20Delegation)